# If statement called, ignore after even if condition has been met

Tags: python

I have a simple if statement in my code

```
if len(bootstrap_node_list_recieved_no_dups) >= min_node_to_complete_boot_strap:
    print "recieved required nodes"
```

Basically I want to know if have enough nodes, I only want this to occur once, as the code will still carry on and be run repeatedly so currently this if statement is run every time as I would expect.

Is there a way to code it so the if statement is run, but after it completes once it is never run again?

The `>=` is required as the input is not a constant.

I hope this is clear, as it's a bit hard to describe.

Update,

i have tried to implement the suggestions but am getting the error

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'flag' referenced before assignment
```

full code below:

```
flag = False

def number_of_duplicates_in_list():
    number_recieved = len(bootstrap_node_list_recieved)
    bootstrap_node_list_recieved_before = len(bootstrap_node_list_recieved_no_dups)

    " this method works in O(n^2) time and is thus very slow on large lists"
    for i in bootstrap_node_list_recieved:
        if i not in bootstrap_node_list_recieved_no_dups:
            bootstrap_node_list_recieved_no_dups.append(i)
    assert len(bootstrap_node_list_recieved_no_dups) >= bootstrap_node_list_recieved_before
    if  len(bootstrap_node_list_recieved_no_dups) >= min_node_to_complete_boot_strap  and flag is False:
        print "recieved required nodes"
        flag = True
```

Comment: `if hasnt_run_yet and len(...): hasnt_run_yet = False; ...`…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have some flagging variable that is changed when the `if` statement is first triggered. The below code is a minimal example which will only print the 'Triggered' statement once, even though all numbers above 3 would trigger the statement if the flag was not also being checked.

```
flag = False

for x in xrange(10):
    if x > 3 and flag is False:
        print 'Triggered'
        flag = True

    # Do something else
```

If you want to do this inside a function, you need to move the flag initialisation into the function as well. Note that re-running the function will reset the flag:

```
def test_func():
    flag = False
    for x in xrange(10):
        if x > 3 and flag is False:
            print 'Triggered'
            flag = True

    # Do something else

test_func()
```

To be able to run the function multiple times but only trigger the `if` statement and change the flag once, you need to link the flag to the function calls. A simple method of doing this is to pass and return the flag on each call:

```
flag = False

def test_func(flag):
    for x in xrange(10):
        if x > 3 and flag is False:
            print 'Triggered'
            flag = True

    # Do something else
    return flag

flag = test_func(flag)
flag = test_func(flag)
```

Here, the flag is define outside of the function and passed to each function when called. If not triggered, it passes through without change. If triggered, it is changed and its state passed back outside the function.

Other approaches could be defining a `global` variable or building a class with the flag as an object variable and accessing it via `self`.

Comment: Thanks i have tried this method but keep getting UnboundLocalError: local variable 'flag' referenced before assignment

Comment: Iv updated the answer with two solutions depending on your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Define `flag` to be global within number_of_duplicates_in_list. Otherwise, you can only read it.